# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Gender' not found

Tags: r

I read the data from .csv file, and ran the following commands

`plsFit <- train(CollegePlans ~ .,data = training,method = "pls",preProc = c("center", "scale"));

toPredict <- c("Female",35800,124,"Not Encouraged","Does not plan to attend")

plsClasses <- predict(plsFit, newdata = toPredict)`
and got the following error
`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Gender' not found`

Here is a structure:

```
str(training) 
'data.frame':   5401 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Gender             : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ ParentIncome       : int  53900 24900 65800 11440 16700 47630 39820 4860 65340 66550 ...
 $ IQ                 : int  118 87 93 117 102 100 127 95 100 112 ...
 $ ParentEncouragement: Factor w/ 2 levels "Encouraged","Not Encouraged": 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CollegePlans       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Does not plan to attend",..: 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toPredict needs to be a dataframe too, even if only one row. e.g.

```
toPredict <- data.frame(
    Gender = "Female",
    ParentIncome = 35800,
    IQ = 124,
    ParentEncouragement = "Not Encouraged",
    CollegePlans = "Does not plan to attend"
)
```